# Which program should use for an Image with description

Tags: image-editing, layout, type, label

I have an Online Shop, I'll in my Website Dress to sell, I to want habe as this image to show,

[image]

My question is which program need for have same what inside of rectangle is, the Black Circle and the Line which connect to it.

I'm Linux user...

Comment: Any drawing or photo application can create type, a filled circle, and a line.

Comment: thanks for you answer, how does it with Gimp ?, how filled circle and give the and I give the line different thickness as the image to show ?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched for basic tutorials on how to use Gimp? This is all very rudimentary.

Comment: Now I'm search on youtube example, how to doing it with Gimp...

Comment: If this is going on a website, it's usually good to make the text more accessible by either doing the text in HTML or providing a good fallback for users who can't use full images. Also keep in mind responsiveness, like small screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare the photo and remove the background from it - if needed - in GIMP. Paste it to Inkscape and add texts, numbers. +  auxiliary lines, curves colored areas there. Vector editing in GIMP is possible, but it's very clumsy due poor tools, Inkscape is much more flexible and allows you to export the result as SVG or in raster formats (for ex. JPG, with transparency use PNG)

If you have made in GIMP the background transparent, the transparency stays when the image is pasted to Inkscape. As well you can import a PNG to Inkscape for keeping the transparency.

None of these programs knows anything useful of CMYK printing. I guess it's no problem in your case.

Website programmers may build their photo-text-graphics compositions in higher level in the web page builder. I guess you are not going to do it.

Comment: Very Thanks for your answer, because is my First Time, who i to work with Inkscape, now i'll lern it, i now to reading that Inkscape is beter for Vector graphic as Gimp...

Comment: You obviously use some webshop platform. Ask them which is the best format to keep texts and auxiliary graphics sharp (=non-pixelated). As already commented by others: The webpage should be constructed as responsive i.e. as easy to use with a phone as with a wide screen desktop PC. If the platform you use makes this possible you should also prepare your material to support this feature.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are not tech savvy, it might be easier to use something like Figma. It's quite simple to use and should work well for something like your example.

There is no need to install any software on your computer. There's an online version of Figma and you can use it directly in your browser. It's also free!

Here's a screenshot showing a very quick and simple layout I made in Figma

[image]

You can easily drop in an image, type some text, draw circles, add a fill, draw lines, change the stroke colour etc. Once you have completed the layout Group all the elements and Export the Group as a PNG imgage for use on your website.

Here's an example of the above layout exported as a PNG. You can also export as SVG if the text, lines, and shapes need to be vector.

[image]

Comment: Very thanks! it is very easy to work...I wish you a nice Weekend !